# How do I show pop up on clicking anywhere inside body using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have to show a popup message to display the network connection on click of anywhere in the body of page if Internet is available. Using JavaScript, we can do it by using addeventlister like below.

But how do I achieve this?

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in AngularJS is with the `ng-click` directive.  Basically, you encapsulate your alert and network status checking code in a scope method in the page's controller.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Click the button';
  $scope.showMessage = function() {
    // Simple example that doesn't check network status or
    // display anything of real value other than verifying
    // that a click anywhere on the page will invoke this method
    alert('hello');
  }
});
```

Once this is done, you will place the `ng-click="showMessage"` directive on the element that you want the event listener attached to. In this example, I use the entire body.

```
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-click="showMessage()">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <p>Click anywhere</p>
  </body>
```

[Here is a basic plunk, to test it out.](http://plnkr.co/edit/IhXDRLzhFteGLBzDCgQa?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in AngularJS:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Angular</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    </body>
</html>
```

#### script.js

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    document.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
}])
```

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3El6XnhK9LDMJQ00gXD2?p=preview). Click on anywhere on the page, you would see `alert` popping up.